# How to search with an array in Yii2 search model

Tags: php, yii2, many-to-many, yii2-model

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new SubjectSearch();
    $searchModel->search()->query->andFilterWhere(['in','subjectID',[1,2,3]]);
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

I've tried different ways like

```
$searchModel->subjectID = [1,2,3]

$searchModel->search()->query->andFilterWhere(['in','subjectID',[1,2,3]]);
```

But they doesn't work for me.

Actually, ArrayDataprovider might seem to be a better  solution in this case, but Array Dataprovide won't work with filters.

BTW, the real question is to search with ManyToMany Relationship.

many Users to many Groups.
many Groups to many Subjects.

UserGroupTbl contains UserID and GroupID
SubjectGroup contains SubjectID and GroupID

I'm trying to do that with:

```
$groups = $appUser->getGroups();
$subjectIDs = [];
foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $subjectIDs[] = $group->getSubjectIDs
}
$searchModel = new SubjectSearch();
$searchModel->subjectID = $subjectIDs;
```

But that doesn't work and is certainly not a good method

Please help me a little bit with it.

================Update==============

```
    $searchModel = new SubjectSearch();
    $searchModel->subjectID = [1,2];
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

Result in "Array to string conversion" error.

```
    $searchModel = new SubjectSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->query->andFilterWhere(['in','subjectID',[1,2]]);;
```

This method actually worked.
BTW, do you have a little bit advice about handling many to many searching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call search you will get a new query object so you can't add parameters to it, use this method:

```
$searchModel = new SubjectSearch();
$searchModel->subjectID = [1,2,3];
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

In the SubjectSearch model you should have this in the search function:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(
   [
      ...
      'subjectId' => $this->subjectID,
      ...
   ]
);
```

Comment: That's strange. I thought the $searchModel->subjectID = [1,2,3]; thing doesn't work at all. They just return everything. I'll try it later and see if I've done anything wrong

Answer (score 4):

You will not believe that today I was also stuck in same situation.
Where I thought `IN` will work as how I wanted. But, strangely not worked for me.

***I tried.***

```
$dataProvider->query->andFilterWhere(['IN','subjectID', $this->subjectID]);
```

In Yii Debugger, this query was changed to:

> SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE (condition) AND (subjectID = '1,2') ...

Then, I Changed my query to

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['subjectID' => $this->subjectID]);
```

And, checked in Yii Debugger, the query was automatically changed to:

> SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE (condition) AND (subjectID IN ('1,2'))
>   ...

Which I was looking for.

***Updated Code***

I will suggest you to follow the code given below. It will work. *@Ed209's Answer* is right too.

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $searchModel = new SubjectSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

**SubjectSearch.php**

```
class SubjectSearch {
  .
  .
  .

  public function search($params) {
    $query = SubjectSearch::find();

    $this->load($params);

    if($this->subjectID != null){
      $query->andFilterWhere(['subjectID' => $this->subjectID]);
    }

    // You can add more clauses here to make your data more appropriate.


    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => $query,
      'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 20),
    ]);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
      return $dataProvider;
    }
    return $dataProvider;
  }  

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. You both answered my question but Ed209 answered earlier.
So I'll just choose his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i suggest you to use the following in which you don't need to add some extra condition like where or andWhere

```
    public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new SubjectSearch();
    $queryData = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
     $conditionData = [\yii\helpers\StringHelper::basename(($searchModel) => ['IN','subjectID'],[1,2,3]];
     $searchData = array_merge_recursive($queryData, $conditionData);
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($searchData);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

This code works for me very smoothly. I hope it will help you too

Comment: How can i set two condition for diferents columns?

Comment: add other index in array like:  $conditionData = [\yii\helpers\StringHelper::basename(($searchModel) => ['IN','studentid'],[1,2]]